# Javascript html slicing

Tags: javascript, html

I want the text to only show "here" for example, but it doesn't work.
The text changes often but the word I need stays on a fixed position. I would like to access that word.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    var y = x.slice(16,19);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">Changable tekst here</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is the DOM Node object, you cannot use string methods on it. Use `innerHTML` property on it to get the innerHTML of an element.

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
//                                      ^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, use `x.slice(16, 20);` to get the word `here` from the text.

```html
<p id="demo">Changable tekst here</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
    var y = x.slice(16, 20);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y;
  }
</script>
```